# How to build akka distribution from source code

Tags: akka

I couldn't foud how to build akka from source code using sbt tool or somewhere to download a akka distribution.

Is there any one could help me ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Build instructions are available here: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#sbt

There used to be an akka distribution available for download somewhere but I can't find it anymore right now. I however doubt that you need it to get started with akka. You can instead follow the getting started guide http://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-scala/, or have a look at the documentation http://akka.io/docs/.